# Variable userFetched is used before being assigned in Firebase cloud functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

There are a lots of similar questions but none of them solve my query.

Here is my code:

```
if (commandFn === "/fetch") {
  let userFetched: string;
  returnText = `${commandFn} used with ${commandArg}`;
  admin.database
    .ref(`/Users/` + commandArg + "/userdata")
    .once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
      userFetched = snapshot.val().userdata;
    });

  return res.status(200).send({
    method: "sendMessage",
    chat_id,
    text: `${returnText} /n ${userFetched}`,
  });
}
```

Why is it saying that variable isn't assigned? In other functions where I don't have to use the admin.database feature I simply added the return statement in the if block.

There are lots of if-else statements in my code which change the text to be returned but the same error. So I have to add the return statement all the times in each if-else block.

But when I'm using admin.database feature I cannot do that. 
Again I have seen other similar QUESTIONS but those didn't answer mine.

This is yet another chunk of code facing the same issue:

```
let numberOfWords: number
    for (let index = 1 ; index <= userCommandSlicedLength; index++) {  
      let lastChar: string = '' 
      let currentChar: string = ''
      currentChar = userCommandSliced.charAt(index)
      lastChar = userCommandSliced.charAt(index-1)
      if (currentChar === " " && lastChar !== " ") {
        numberOfWords = numberOfWords + 1
      }  
      else if (currentChar === " " && lastChar === " ") {    // This is a test String.
       numberOfWords = numberOfWords + 0 
      }   
    }

    const finalNumberOfWords: number = numberOfWords

    console.log(`Number of words final are = ${finalNumberOfWords}`)
```

The issue for 2nd code:

```
src/index.ts:88:25 - error TS2454: Variable 'numberOfWords' is used before being assigned.

88         numberOfWords = numberOfWords + 1
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/index.ts:91:24 - error TS2454: Variable 'numberOfWords' is used before being assigned.

91        numberOfWords = numberOfWords + 0
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/index.ts:95:40 - error TS2454: Variable 'numberOfWords' is used before being assigned.

95     const finalNumberOfWords: number = numberOfWords
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be initialized with a value then only you can add values

```
userFetched
```

is declared as string we cant add a object there, intialize it as object.

and

```
numberOfWords
```

should be intialized with 0 so you can increment it

Answer (score 0):

The variable `userFetched` is undefined, because it is assigned asynchronously within the `Promise.then()`.

The following code should work as expected.

```
if (commandFn === "/fetch") {
  let userFetched: string;
  returnText = `${commandFn} used with ${commandArg}`;
  admin.database
    .ref(`/Users/` + commandArg + "/userdata")
    .once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
      userFetched = snapshot.val().userdata;
      return res.status(200).send({
        method: "sendMessage",
        chat_id,
        text: `${returnText} /n ${userFetched}`,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
```

### Edit based on comments

This is how I would do it to reduce `res.send` statements.

```
async function MyCloudFunction() {
  let userFetched: string;
  if (commandFn === "/fetch") {
    const snapshot = await admin.database
      .ref(`/Users/` + commandArg + "/userdata")
      .once("value");
    userFetched = snapshot.val().userdata;
  }
  //   DO OTHER STUFF
  return res.status(200).send({
    method: "sendMessage",
    chat_id,
    text: `${returnText} /n ${userFetched}`,
  });
}
```

Comment: It returning value as Undefined. Value of userFetched is undefined.. the path is correct